# Expressions of time: "...by the time" vs "...the moment"

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, time

> I phoned her_____ I heard the news.
>
> 1. minute
> 2. during
> 3. by the time
> 4. the moment

I know that correct answer is "the moment"; yet I don't comprehend why it is right answer. Can we substitute "by the time" in the place of "the moment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The moment* could be substituted by *when* or *as soon as* in your sentence. So, it is correct. What is meant here is "Just when I heard the news, I phoned her." In other words, "The moment I heard the news, I phoned her." **Note** that fist this person heard the news and right after that he phoned.

*By the time* is used for saying what has already happened at the time that something else happens. It would be correct to say "I had phoned her by the time I heard the news". But in this case the situation is different. It means he phoned and then heard the news.

All in all, *the moment* is the only correct option out of the ones given.

Comment: If there was the article in "the minute" that would also be acceptable. Does the definite article play a significant role here?

Comment: Yes, "the minute I hear the news" is OK.

Comment: Yes, I know *that* but does the OP?

Comment: As far as I know, the OP receives messages about all the comments. So, I hope mine will be read. I'm not sure I should edit the answer because the question is about "by the time" and "the moment", not "minute" and "during".

Comment: No, the OP is not notified every time someone posts a comment, he or she is only notified if that comment is posted underneath their question.